# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. Android 3.0+ lombok

Tags: android, gradle, lombok, android-studio-3.0

I want use lombok in Android Studio 3.0

I get error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - lombok-1.16.18.jar (org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18)
  Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
  See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

My gradle dependency

```
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
```

Comment: Ok did you tried this : `compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"`

Comment: yes. but I get error - Error:(19, 1) error: package javax.annotation does not exist

Comment: Then this should work : `compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18' annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
```

You can disable the generation of `javax.annotation.Generated` by putting the following line in a `lombok.config` file in one of the top directories of your project:

```
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
```

See the [configuration documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) for more information.