# Annotation processors error for android 3.0

Tags: android

Can someone please help me out with this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - compiler-4.4.0.jar (compiler-4.4.0.jar)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See  https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

gradle file:

```
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

   defaultConfig { 
   applicationId "com.finalyear.myproject" 
   minSdkVersion 17 
   targetSdkVersion 
   26 versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" 
            }
    }
```

Comment: is it for android v3.0 or androidstudio 3.0

Comment: Please show us your application level `build.gradle`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112106/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appjavaprecompiledebug-android-3-0-lombok

Comment: This is my build.gradle       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.finalyear.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Comment: Please go through the doc here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html